# Can bash consume the same fifo from two separate commands?

Tags: bash, grep, fifo

I have a huge data source that I'm filtering using some `grep`s.

Here's basically what I'm doing right now:

```
#!/bin/bash
param1='something'
param2='another'
param3='yep'
echo $(avro-read /log/huge_data | grep $param1 | grep "$param2-" | grep $param3 | wc -l) / $(avro-read /log/ap/huge_data | grep $param1 | grep -v "$param2-" | grep $param3 | wc -l) | bc -l
```

Notice how I'm doing mostly the same filtering twice (a single difference the second time), taking the count of each, and dividing the final result. This is definitely a hacky thing to do, but I'd like to try and speed it up just a bit and only perform the initial filtering once without using a temp file.

I tried using a fifo, but I'm not sure if it's possible to have two processes in one script reading from it, as well as have a third process "wait" until both are done to compute the final result. I also looked into using `tee`, but again not sure how to synchronize the resulting sub processes.

EDIT: Solved this myself using https://superuser.com/a/561248/43649, but marked another suggestion as the answer.

Comment: No; once one process reads data from the fifo, that data is gone and will not be seen by the other process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to avoid creating temporary files (or storing the output of grep in a variable), you can feed it to a for loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
yay=0
nay=0

for line in `avro-read /log/huge_data | grep $param1 | grep $param3`; do
    [[ $line =~ $param2- ]] && yay=$(($yay + 1)) || nay=$(($nay + 1))
done

echo $yay / $nay \* 100 | bc -l

unset IFS
```

---

I've created a modified version of the approach in [your self-answer](https://superuser.com/a/561248) that won't require temporary files:

```
#!/bin/bash

(avro-read /log/huge_data | grep $param1 | grep $param3 | tee \
     >(echo yay=`grep -c "$param2-"`) \
     >(echo nay=`grep -vc "$param2-"`) \
     >/dev/null | cat ; echo 'echo $yay / $nay \* 100 | bc -l') | sh
```

The output of the individual `grep -c` commands and the `echo` command get printed as

```
yay=123
nay=456
echo $yay / $nay \* 100 | bc -l
```

to avoid race conditions<sup>1</sup>. Piping to `sh` executes the printed commands.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Whichever `grep -c` command finishes first will print the first line of output.</sub>

Comment: Super cool way to loop through the data.

Comment: Great -- that's a "need to remember" trick to get the values out of the process substitutions :)

Comment: Wow! Super cool way of doing it. Thanks for adapting my answer! There is definitely a lot to learn from this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
param1='something'
param2='another'
param3='yep'

avro-read /log/huge_data | grep $param1 | grep $param3 \
| tee \
>(grep "$param2-" | wc -l | tr -d '\n' > has_count) \
>(grep -v "$param2-" | wc -l | tr -d '\n' > not_count) \
> /dev/null

echo $(cat has_count | tr -d '\n') '/' $(cat not_count | tr -d 'n') '* 100' | bc -l
```

So rather than relying on a fifo or temp file, I used `tee` to split the stream into two separate processes that just output a count! This way I don't need to try and synchronize the two processes before trying to divide the counts.

Comment: You are using two temp files...

Comment: Very interesting! I've included a modification of your approach in my answer that doesn't require temporary files.

Comment: By "not relying on a temp file" in this case, I meant a temp file full of actual data. In this case, it's just storing a number.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, `zsh` has a feature, called MULTIOS. Therewith it's possible to connect one process to two fifo's. If that's an option here a small demo:

```
#!/bin/zsh -f

setopt multios

mkfifo f1 f2 2> /dev/null

param1='something'
param2='another'
param3='yep'

{ avro-read /log/huge_data | grep $param1 | grep $param3 } > f1 > f2 &

( cat f1 | grep $param2 | wc -l > value1 ) &!
value2=$(cat f2 | grep -v $param2 | wc -l)

print $(( 1. * $( cat value1 ) / $value2 ))

rm value1
```

However, I could not figure out a way to get round the creation of the temporary file `value1`, which should be probably avoided as pointed out by Dennis. But perhaps you'll like this solution nevertheless.